# awk match field with variable regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I need to sort a series of .csv patient demographic reports according to (semi-arbitrary) location, as designated by zip code.

I wrote a bash script parsing a file which lists all the clinics and their assigned zip codes.  However I can't figure out how to code the regex into my awk statement.

The zip codes file:

```
$   cat clinics
south;23456|23458|23451
north;23452|23454|23459
west;23453|23455|23457
```

The sample data file:

```
$   head sample.csv
FirstName,LastName,MiddleName,Address,City,State,Zip,Plus4,Phone,MoveDate,OwnerShip,EstValue,ChildCode,MailInd,MoveDist,Age,Income
John,Smith,,123 Main Street,Hudson,NC,23456,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,0,03,0,0,0,0,05
Jim,Smith,,123 Main Street,Lenoir,NC,23457,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,03,0,0,0,0,06
Joe,Smith,,123 Main Street,Greensboro,NC,23457,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,02,4,1,0,4,08
Jimmy,Smith,,123 Main Street,Statesville,NC,23457,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,05,2,1,1,2,13
Jimmy,Smits,,123 Main Street,Charlotte,NC,23456,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,04,1,1,4,4,18
J Jonah,Smith,,123 Main Street,Fayetteville,NC,23458,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,03,1,1,3,4,01
James,Smith,,123 Main Street,Maiden,NC,23459,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,00,4,1,0,2,18
Jahosephat,Smith,,123 Main Street,Hudson,NC,23459,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,00,4,1,0,1,02
Jane,Smith,,123 Main Street,Charlotte,NC,23451,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,05,4,1,0,3,06
```

Correlating a clinic with its zip codes is easy.  And I can match the south clinic using `awk` and a regex:

```
$   awk -F, '$7 ~ "23456|23458|23451"' sample.csv
John,Smith,,123 Main Street,Hudson,NC,23456,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,0,03,0,0,0,0,05
Jimmy,Smits,,123 Main Street,Charlotte,NC,23456,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,04,1,1,4,4,18
J Jonah,Smith,,123 Main Street,Fayetteville,NC,23458,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,03,1,1,3,4,01
Jane,Smith,,123 Main Street,Charlotte,NC,23451,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,05,4,1,0,3,06
```

However, when I try substituting a string variable (like my script must do), I can't figure out how to escape the variable so `awk` likes it:

```
$   Zips="23456|23458|23451"
$   awk -F, '$7 ~ "$Zips"' sample.csv
$   awk -F, '$7 ~ /$Zips/' sample.csv
$   awk -F, '$7 ~ /\$Zips/' sample.csv
$   awk -F, '$7 ~ /\\$Zips/' sample.csv
$
```

UPDATE:

In addition to letting `awk` parse the variable *I tried feeding it a shell-expanded variable; that didn't work, but **I've since learned that was wrong anyway*** (thank you to @haifzhan and @EdMorton).

I tried

```
awk -F, "\$7 ~ $Zips" sample.csv
awk -F, '$7 ~ '"\"/$Zips/\"" sample.csv
awk -F, '{$7 ~ ' "/$Zips/" ' }' sample.csv
```

and a dozen similar permutations. I now understand this was sorely unappreciative of awk's capabilities and am therefore glad I didn't think of @EdMorton's suggestion in comments--even though I'm annoyed I didn't think of it--as my knowledge of awk wouldn't have improved. Each attempt either returned null or failed with an error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    {$7 ~ >>>  23456\ <<< 23458|23451}
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

---

UPDATE (`grep`): I've spotted my logic (not syntax) oversight and would remove this section if that wouldn't render existing comments incoherent...

I tried `grep`, erroneously assuming my test scaled properly--it didn't.

```
grep -E ','"$Zips"',' $SrcFile >> $OutFile
```

(which means)

```
match any of:
",23456"
"23458"
"23451,"
```

For my 50-line sample file, the results between `grep` and `awk` are the same, but the actual 8000-line file contained precisely the sort of matches I'd feared.

Thanks to all for reading.

Comment: That grep statement does mean what you think it does, idk why you wouldn't expect that to produce the desired output from that sample input. It's the wrong approach of course since it is searching across the whole of every line and not just the 7th field but it will produce output. `grep -E ",($Zips),"` would have been a bit better but still wrong.

Comment: @EdMorton well my RegExFu is not very strong, which was convoluted here by my unfamiliarity with the more powerful aspects of `awk`.  I wasn't sure if the regex would include the commas--or I should say I wasn't sure how to specify whether it does.  I was concerned if a phone number contains "23456" then it would be aggregated incorrectly.  I actually had the parenthesis but didn't xfer them to the sanitized version of my question.  Thanks a ton for the supporting info.

Comment: for this specific example my prior comment should state '23458' instead of '23456'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-v` to declare the varialbe

```
awk -F, -v zips="23456|23458|23451" '$7 ~ zips' sample.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

To do this directly as you stated, you need to use double-quotes to allow `$Zips` to be substituted, and then escape some of the characters with a '\':

```
Zips="23456|23458|23451"
awk -F, "\$7 ~ \"$Zips\"" foo
```

Comment: No, never do this, it is wrong in a couple of different ways. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to access the values of shell variables in awk scripts and see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35189456/1745001 for the right answer to this question. If you WERE going to do this then the syntactically correct implementation would be `awk -F, '$7 ~ /'"$Zips"'/' foo` but letting shell variables expand to become part of the body of the awk script before the awk interpreter sees it is always the wrong approach.

Comment: @Brian Yes, my script does precisely that.  It establishes the variables by parsing the lines in 'clinics.csv' and then fails because I didn't know about `-v` per @haifzhan

Comment: @EdMorton  good to know.  I've historically used awk for little more than `'{print $3" "$4" "$7}'` constructs, so links like that help immensely.  Thank you

Answer (score -2):

You have to put your quotes correct.  Inside single quotes no shell variable expansion happens.  And you have single quote around your whole awk program.  But it works when you put your quotes just like you did in the grep example:  single quote around everything, except the shell variable, which must be in double quotes (to expand) to protect the pipe chars for the shell:

```
awk -F, '$7 ~ '"/$Zips/" sample.csv
```

This gives result:

```
$ awk -F, '$7 ~ '"/$Zips/" sample.csv 
John,Smith,,123 Main Street,Hudson,NC,23456,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,0,03,0,0,0,0,05
Jimmy,Smits,,123 Main Street,Charlotte,NC,23456,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,04,1,1,4,4,18
J Jonah,Smith,,123 Main Street,Fayetteville,NC,23458,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,03,1,1,3,4,01
Jane,Smith,,123 Main Street,Charlotte,NC,23451,1234,5555555555,01/03/2004,3,05,4,1,0,3,06
```

Comment: @PBI, yes I know how single- and double-quotes affect variable expansion.  Not knowing the correct way I actually tried exactly what you describe  (it produces a syntax error "awk: bailing out at source line 1").  Many of my failed attempts hinged on trying to escape quotes and "$".  I considered listing them but knew (a) my question was already plenty long, and (b) they'd only be targets of "u r dum" while cluttering the true question

Comment: So just put single quotes (easiest to protect the $7 and spaces) around that part, than put double quotes around the part that contains the variable expanded by the shell.

Comment: @PBI No, do not do that as you'd still end up expanding the shell variable contents to become part of the awk script (not a variable) before the awk interpretter gets to parse the script and so you tightly couple the shell variable to awk syntax and make the whole script susceptible to weird and wonderful failures with obscure error messages (if you're lucky) given various contents of the shell variable. Just do what the accepted answer says: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35189456/1745001.

Comment: @EdMorton - Completely agree. But my answer is to the question why his grep worked, and his awk did not work.

Comment: @PBI I don't want to seem unappreciative; as I stated above, I tried shell pre-expansion before posting here.  Advice by @EdMorton aside (which I also didn't know) I tried `awk -F, '$7 ~ '"\"/$Zips/\"" sample.csv` and `awk -F, '{$7 ~ ' "/$Zips/" ' }' sample.csv` and a dozen similar permutations.  Each either returned null or failed with an error.

Comment: You have to build 1 string which has to get the correct syntax for awk:  `$7 ~ /23456|23458|23451/` (no curly braces here!). It contains chars interpreted by the shell and thus must be quoted.  Single quotes protect everything, except single quote itself.  But the numbers are replaced by a shell variable, only expanded when inside double quotes. So we just put the desired quotes around that part. Without adding an extra space between. Yes, the close single quote is right before the open double quote. An extra space breaks the string into 2 args. No extra double quotes either.

Comment: SOrry, I shouldn't have added spaces; on my screen the single quote next to a double looked so much like a solitary double quote I added the space for legibility (which in retrospect was dumb since I enclosed it in code tags).

Comment: Prior to posting my question my ignorance of awk compounded itself when I didn't know which characters I should be trying to escape. I found many examples of one or the other `(compare $7 to a given string|put $var through awk)` but none combined the two.  I escaped $, braces, string delimiter /, quotes... I see now what you meant. Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: Of course I didn't notice until just now you'd edited your answer.  The command it shows now isn't in my history, but the one it showed yesterday ...  I'd tried that before posting :-)